# Issue with Keycloak and OidcClient in C# - IdentityToken is null

Tags: c#, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, oidc-client

I’m using Keycloak for authentication in my C# application. I’m using the OidcClient library to handle the authentication process. However, I’m encountering an issue: after a successful login, the IdentityToken is null while the AccessToken is valid.

Here’s a snippet of my code:

```
var result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
if (result == null || result.IsError)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Error in connection: {result?.Error ?? "No error"}");
}
result.AccessToken; // OK
result.IdentityToken; //Null
```

For this call scope : `openid offline_access`
And my client in keycloak is `OpenIdConnect`

The connection works in itself, but I need the IdentityToken for the logout.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I’ve searched for answers, but everything that came close to a response was too old and did not correspond to the latest version of Keycloak. (need to 22.0.3)

**Edit :**
Config in my dev

````
{

 "clientId": "appclient",

 "name": "App ClientId",

 "description": "",

 "rootUrl": "",

 "adminUrl": "",

 "baseUrl": "",

 "surrogateAuthRequired": false,

 "enabled": true,

 "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,

 "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",

 "redirectUris": [

   "app://authcallback/*"

 ],

 "webOrigins": [],

 "notBefore": 0,

 "bearerOnly": false,

 "consentRequired": false,

 "standardFlowEnabled": true,

 "implicitFlowEnabled": false,

 "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,

 "serviceAccountsEnabled": false,

 "publicClient": true,

 "frontchannelLogout": true,

 "protocol": "openid-connect",

 "attributes": {

   "client.secret.creation.time": "1697036807",

   "post.logout.redirect.uris": "app://authcallback/*",

   "oauth2.device.authorization.grant.enabled": "true",

   "backchannel.logout.revoke.offline.tokens": "true",

   "use.refresh.tokens": "true",

   "oidc.ciba.grant.enabled": "false",

   "backchannel.logout.session.required": "true",

   "client_credentials.use_refresh_token": "false",

   "acr.loa.map": "{}",

   "require.pushed.authorization.requests": "false",

   "tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens": "false",

   "display.on.consent.screen": "false",

   "token.response.type.bearer.lower-case": "false"

 },

 "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},

 "fullScopeAllowed": true,

 "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,

 "protocolMappers": [

   {

     "name": "Client IP Address",

     "protocol": "openid-connect",

     "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",

     "consentRequired": false,

     "config": {

       "user.session.note": "clientAddress",

       "id.token.claim": "true",

       "access.token.claim": "true",

       "claim.name": "clientAddress",

       "jsonType.label": "String"

     }

   },

   {

     "name": "Client ID",

     "protocol": "openid-connect",

     "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",

     "consentRequired": false,

     "config": {

       "user.session.note": "client_id",

       "id.token.claim": "true",

       "access.token.claim": "true",

       "claim.name": "client_id",

       "jsonType.label": "String"

     }

   },

   {

     "name": "Client Host",

     "protocol": "openid-connect",

     "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",

     "consentRequired": false,

     "config": {

       "user.session.note": "clientHost",

       "id.token.claim": "true",

       "access.token.claim": "true",

       "claim.name": "clientHost",

       "jsonType.label": "String"

     }

   }

 ],

 "defaultClientScopes": [

   "web-origins",

   "acr",

   "openid",

   "roles",

   "profile",

   "user"

 ],

 "optionalClientScopes": [

   "address",

   "phone",

   "offline_access",

   "microprofile-jwt",

   "email"

 ],

 "access": {

   "view": true,

   "configure": true,

   "manage": true

 }

}```
````

Comment: What OIDC grant and flow are you using?

Comment: I have enabled the ‘Standard Flow’, ‘Direct Access Grants’, and ‘OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant’ in my application. Could this be related to the issue I’m experiencing with the IdentityToken being null?

Comment: Can you share your entire Client configuration (except client_secret values, ofc)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited my message with the configuration. Let me know if you need more information to understand my problem. Also, I don't have a client_secret for this call because I don't need one.

Comment: @Dai Are you an idea ?

Comment: You'll have to buy me dinner first